# What does this warning about ApiConfigSource mean?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I get this warning in the console while running my Google App Engine application in the development server :

> WARNING: Fail to load endpoint class class com.mydomain.MyClassEndpoint with ApiConfigSource class com.google.api.server.spi.config.datastore.ApiConfigDatastoreReader

The warning seem to appear when the Android app accesses the endpoint not when I start the development server.

What does it mean and how can I solves it ?

I am using :
GAE-J : 1.8.3, JDO, Eclipse Kepler + GPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per google guys, you can ignore this warning. It's a 1.8.3 bug. "The message shouldn't be appearing, and will be correctly hidden in a future release"
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9824